# How to disable spring batch console logging?

Tags: spring-boot, log4j, spring-batch, logback

I'm using sprig batch with spring boot (2.5.5). How do I disable console logging created by batch jobs and steps? Is there any configuration prorerty to directly disable this

```
INFO 1 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobOperator : Locating parameters for next instance of job with name=myJob
INFO 1 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobOperator : Attempting to launch job with name=myJob and parameters={run.id=3970, now=2021-10-05T15:30:02.154224900Z}
INFO 1 --- [cTaskExecutor-3] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=myJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{run.id=3970, now=2021-10-05T15:30:02.154224900Z}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manage this by changing the log level to `ERROR` OR `DEBUG`

```
org.springframework.batch=ERROR
```

Comment: Tried `logging.level.org.springframework.batch.level=ERROR` but logging is still there

Comment: @Annon, remove the trailing `.level`: `logging.level.org.springframework.batch=ERROR` (cf. [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.log-levels)).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz that worked. thanks